# Persisting Eloquent Builder Instance in Laravel Livewire

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-livewire

there is an instance of `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` that I would like to persist when instantiate (during the `mount` lifecycle hook) so that I can use it for queries. The problem is I would not be able to set it as public property since it will throw a `Livewire\Exceptions\PublicPropertyTypeNotAllowedException` (as follows). I would not be able to save it in session as well since it is a PDO instance and PDO instances can't be serialized or unserialized.
[image]

Any idea guys?

**Edit:**

Controller:

```
public function index() {
    $tableQuery = User::query();

    return view('table', compact('tableQuery'));
    }
```

table.blade.php:

```
<livewire:table
   :tableQuery=$tableQuery
>
```

App\Http\Livewire\Table:

```
class Table extends Component{
    private $tableQuery;
    
    public function mount($tableQuery){
        $this->tableQuery = $tableQuery;
    }
    
    public function render(){
        return view('livewire.table');
    }
}
```

Comment: can u put your component code ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use Model inside `livewire`

```php
class Table extends Component{
    public $tableQuery;
    
    public function mount(){
        $this->tableQuery =  User::query();;
     }
    
    public function render(){
        return view('livewire.table');
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the component should be made dynamically so that other models can reuse this as well, nevertheless it gave me a spark and I appreciate it, thanks!